# Spring cache/fallback framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

My use case is that I want to cache certain request:response in my service caller classes:

```
public class Abc{
  public Response serviceCall(Request r){}
}

public class Memcached{
 public Response get(Request r){}

public void put(Request r, Response rs){}
}
```

I want to use memcached for caching . The request would be the key and value would be the response. Whenever serviceCall() is called I want to check if request is already present in cache if so then return response from the cache.
If not then actually execute serviceCall() method and put request:response key:value in memcached

Is there any way in spring to achieve the same.

I did look into @Cacheable here http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial

But I am unable to understand how I make spring use my "Memcached" class, more specifically where do I wire my "Memcached" class so that it is available to class "Abc" in above example

Could you please help . I am working in spring boot completely annotation based and looking for annotation based solution

Answer (score 3):

Spring caching doesn't support Memcached by out-of-the-box ([Supported Cache Providers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html#_supported_cache_providers)).

If you want to use Memcached in your project please check out [Memcached Spring Boot](https://github.com/sixhours-team/memcached-spring-boot) caching library.

There is also an [example Java project](https://github.com/sixhours-team/spring-boot-memcached-demo-java) of how to use Memcached with Spring.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the memcached class. Just put the `@Cacheable` annotation on Abc.serviceCall as per the baeldung tutorial.

Comment: but i want to use my memcached class , how will Abc.serviceCall know to use my "Memcached" class

Comment: Why do you want to use that rather than letting the Spring caching API do all the work for you ?

Comment: In the question I have mentioned memcahed for keeping the question simple , it is actually  a custom cache we have created for our specific use cases